# How to Run WebTest Example?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webtest

I'm trying to understand how to use [WebTest](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/) to do integration testing and I'm stuck on the first example.

I've tried to follow the instructions.  First I created a module that contains the code I want to test:

```
# functions.py
def application(environ, start_response):
    """docstring for application"""
    # I added body, otherwise you get an undefined variable error
    body = 'foobar'
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf8'),
               ('Content-Length', str(len(body)))]
    start_response('200 OK', headers)
    return [body]
```

Then I created a test runner file:

```
# test.py
from webtest import TestApp
from functions import application

app = TestApp(application)
resp = app.get('/')
assert resp.status == '200 OK'
assert resp.status_int == 200
```

When I execute test.py, I get the following error:

AssertionError: Iterator  returned a non- object: 'foobar'.

What do I need to do to make this sample code from the WebTest documentation run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSGI the body must be an iterable of bytes:

```
body = b'foobar'
```